# Enable Gutenberg Editor when editing tags

Tags: block-editor, tags

My content creators love the Gutenberg editor in Wordpress. However, they now want to write extensive descriptions for the tag pages for SEO reasons, and WordPress only offers the old default editor, which is clunky and doesn't do everything they want.

Is it possible to enable Gutenberg on the tag editing page?

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet. There is an issue requesting this for categories (https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/17099) which, underneath the hood in WordPress operates quite similar to tags; you may want to follow that issue's progress to learn when this would be possible.